# DisplayTag - where are all the libraries/classes?

Tags: jsp, maven, jar, displaytag

I've downloaded the [DisplayTag 1.2 jars](http://sourceforge.net/projects/displaytag/files/display%20tag%20library/1.2/)

but I cannot find in the jars libraries such as

`org.displaytag.jsptests`

`org.displaytag.test`

`org.displaytag.sample`

and classes such as:

`org.displaytag.decorator.DateColumnDecorator`

My questions are where are they, why are they not in the jar, and what am I supposed to do if I need to use them?

Answer (score 0):

What did you download? SourceForge and Maven Central are the only official binary resources. both are complete for deployment.